# Create DataGrid column separator

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

Is there a way to create a visual separator between two particular columns in a DataGrid? It doesn't need to be fancy, maybe just a double line or a thicker border.

Comment: Are the columns auto-generated or are you specifying the collection?

Comment: I'm specifying the columns by looping through all of the objects and adding any columns not already in the collection. This is to get all of the columns into the table, even though not all of the objects will have all of them defined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case it's something like this

[image]

You can achieve using a custom style:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Fill="Gray"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">        
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Start"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="End"/>
        <!-- Separator column -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="0" Width="2" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Start"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="End"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

If you generate the columns in code-behind, either by autogenerate columns or other, you can still create the separator column by getting the resource from the XAML:

```
DataGridTextColumn s1 = new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Start" };
DataGridTextColumn s2 = new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Start" };
DataGridTextColumn e1 = new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "End" };
DataGridTextColumn e2 = new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "End" };

DataGridTemplateColumn column = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
column.MinWidth = 0;
column.Width = 2;

var separatorStyle = (Style)FindResource("DataGridColumnSeparatorStyle");
column.CellStyle = separatorStyle;

dataGrid.Columns.Add(s1);
dataGrid.Columns.Add(e1);
dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
dataGrid.Columns.Add(s2);
dataGrid.Columns.Add(e2);
```

Comment: While navigating through cells using keyboard, the separator column would receive focus. That's something undesired...

Comment: Vijay Chavda there are many many ways to get around that. You can prevent the column from getting focused easy.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have two options. The simplest option will probably be to use a `Style` and set your `DataGrid.CellStyle` to the defined style.

```
    <Style x:Key="DataGridBorder" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1" />          
    </Style>
    ...
    <DataGrid CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridBorder}">
    ...
```

The other option is to use a `CellTemplate` in conjunction with the `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" Margin="-6,-6,-6,-6">
                    <Grid Margin="6,6,6,6">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />                                                    
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Whatever}" Grid.Column="0" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>                                            
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate> 
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I haven't tested either of these, and you may have to play with the margins a little bit.

Answer (score 4):

Try this. When navigating through cells using keyboard Tab key, it won't focus the seperator column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="2" MaxWidth="2" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResize="False">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">                       
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />                          
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

[Source](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/629163/DataGrid-Visual-Column-Separator)